# Inconsistently getting Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module

Tags: node.js, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm getting inconsistent results from Angular/Karma/Jasmine.  When I run 'npm test', I get:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.10 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 35.0.1916 (Linux)]: Connected on socket aW0Inld7aRhONC2vo04k
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Linux): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.345 secs / 0.016 secs)
```

Then, if I just save the code or test file (no changes), it will sometimes have the same results, sometimes it gives errors:

```
INFO [watcher]: Removed file "/home/www/raffler/entries.js".
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Linux) Raffler controllers RafflerCtrl should start with an empty masterList FAILED
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module raffler due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'raffler' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

This is WITHOUT MAKING CHANGES.  If I stop Karma and restart it works again, but once it fails it always fails.  What gives?  Buggy Angular/Jasmine/Karma?  The code and test are trivial.  Here is the code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('raffler', []);

myApp.controller('RafflerCtrl', function($scope, $log) {
  $scope.$log = $log;
  $scope.masterList = [];
});
```

And here is the test:

```
'use strict';
describe('Raffler controllers', function() {
  describe('RafflerCtrl', function(){
    var scope, ctrl;
    beforeEach(module('raffler'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
        scope = {};
        ctrl = $controller('RafflerCtrl', {$scope:scope});
    }));
    it('should start with an empty masterList', function() {
        expect(scope.masterList.length).toBe(0);
    });
  });
});
```

Am I doing something dumb?  Seems like it should give me consistent results, regardless of my stupidity level...  Thanks.

Comment: Your logs say: *Removed file "/home/www/raffler/entries.js"*. You probably have a tool deleting and recreating this file, and karma sees the deletion and runs the tests.

Answer (score 0):

You were asking if there was a bug.  There is.  The authors of Karma know that there are problems with file watching.  See this issue:  https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/974

Simply saving the file without changes can trigger this behavior.  There's two main ways that files get saved.  The first is to delete the original (or rename it to .bak or something) and then write out the new content.  The second method writes the new content to a temporary file, deletes the original and then moves the temporary file to where the original used to be.  For both of those the file system monitoring can fire an event saying that some files/directories changed.  Node is quick enough to be able to detect the file was removed and tells Karma to stop using it in its tests.  A slightly less used third way is to open the file in a special way to overwrite the contents, which will keep Karma happy.

Back to that bug ... in the above scenario, the globs are not re-evaluated when file system changes are detected.  So it thinks your file was removed.  It never saw that a new file was added, thus it's now out of the test suite.

This bug is bothering me too.  If you've got an idea or a pull request then I'd suggest providing it to the Karma team.  There's already a patch being reviewed that should address these problems - see https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1123.

As a workaround, you can use "set backupcopy=yes" for vim.  There may be settings in other editors to change the behavior so that the file is overwritten instead of replaced.